# Should I use Halfcomplex2Real or Complex2Complex

Tags: c, fft, complex-numbers, fftw, symmetry

Good morning, I'm trying to perform a `2D FFT` as 2 `1-Dimensional FFT`.

The problem setup is the following:

There's a matrix of complex numbers generated by an `inverse FFT` on an **array of real numbers**, lets call it `arr[-nx..+nx][-nz..+nz]`.

Now, since the original array was made up of real numbers, I exploit the symmetry and reduce my array to be `arr[0..nx][-nz..+nz]`.

My problem starts here, with `arr[0..nx][-nz..nz]` provided.
Now I should come back in the domain of real numbers. 
The question is what kind of transformation I should use in the 2 directions?

In `x` I use the `fftw_plan_r2r_1d( .., .., .., FFTW_HC2R, ..)`, called `Half complex to Real` transformation because in that direction I've exploited the symmetry, and that's ok I think.
But in `z` direction I can't figure out if I should use the same transformation or, the `Complex to complex (C2C)` transformation?
What is the correct once and why?

In case of needing [here](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3.pdf), at page 11, the HC2R transformation is briefly described

Thank you

Comment: To easily retrieve a result comparable to that of `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d()`, you can chain a call to `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d()` and a call to the complex-to-complex dft `fftw_plan_many_dft()`. The arguments `howmany` and `istride` can easily be tunned to match the pattern of the output of `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d()`. Contrary to `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d()`, the r2r_1d(...FFTW_HR2C...) separates the real and complex component of each frequency. A second `FFTW_HR2C` can be applied and would be comparable to `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d()` but not exactly similar.

Comment: As quoted on the page 11 of the documentation that you judiciously linked, " Half of these column transforms,  however,  are of imaginary parts,  and should therefore be multiplied by i and combined with the r2hc transforms of the real columns to produce the 2d DFT amplitudes; ...  Thus, ... we recommend using the ordinary r2c/c2r interface". Since you have an array of complex numbers, you can either use c2r transforms or unfold real/imaginary parts and try to use HC2R transforms. The former option seems the most practical.Which one might solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you @francis for your careful explanation. I think I will use the former option as you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "To easily retrieve a result comparable to that of `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d()`, you can chain a call to `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d()` and a call to the complex-to-complex dft `fftw_plan_many_dft()`. The arguments `howmany` and `istride` can easily be tuned to match the pattern of the output of `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d()`. Contrary to `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d()`, the r2r_1d(...FFTW_HR2C...) separates the real and complex component of each frequency. A second `FFTW_HR2C` can be applied and would be comparable to `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d()` but not exactly similar.
>
> As quoted on the page 11 of the documentation that you judiciously linked,
>
> > 'Half of these column transforms, however, are of imaginary parts, and should therefore be multiplied by I and combined with the r2hc transforms of the real columns to produce the 2d DFT amplitudes; ... Thus, ... we recommend using the ordinary r2c/c2r interface.'
>
> Since you have an array of complex numbers, you can either use c2r transforms or unfold real/imaginary parts and try to use HC2R transforms. The former option seems the most practical.Which one might solve your issue?"

-@Francis